# Problema al clonar repositorio GIT (clave publica SSH)

Tags: git

Hace unos años realice una app web y la coloqué en un servidor en el `path:/home/usuario/public_html/app`. Al configurar `git` en el servidor cree el repositorio en `/home/usuario/app.git`.

El problema es que ahora quiero clonar dicho repositorio a mi entorno local de esta manera:

```
git clone ssh://usuario@xxx.com:5918/home/usuario/app.git
```

Pero me tira este error:

```
Cloning into 'app'...
The authenticity of host '[xxx.com]:5918 ([xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:5918)' can't bestablished.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/fQ.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Entiendo que es algo referido a la clave pública, por putty tengo acceso al servidor mediante SSH. Esto lo estoy intentando desde GIT BASH. El tema es que años atrás sí podía trabajar con ese repositorio. La verdad que hace tiempo que no hacia esto y estoy bastante perdido.

Comment: ¿Has generado un par de claves pública/privada en el usuario que estás usando en tu máquina local? ¿Has agregado la clave pública a los autorizados a tu cuenta git ([Settings > SSH y GPG Keys](https://github.com/settings/keys))? ¿Qué sistema operativo estás usando?

Comment: no, en mi maquina local no he generado ninguna clave publica. No estoy usando GitHub, estoy usando un cloud server, con acceso por ssh. En el host cliente uso windows, y el servidor tiene linux, el cual ademas tiene git instalado y el repositorio generado de dicha app web. ¿tendria que generar las claves publicas/privadas en el cliente y de ahi agregarlas al servidor linux?

Comment: En el cliente debes generar el par de claves con `ssh-keygen` y en el servidor (donde está el repositorio git) debes agregar el contenido de la clave pública (el archivo tiene extensión `.pub`) al archivo `.ssh/authorized_keys` del usuario que pones delante del @.

Comment: Oscar, gacias por la ayuda, hice lo que me indicaste, cree las credenciales con git bash desde windows, y copie el contenido en el /home/usuario/.ssh/authorized_keys del servidor. Tuve que crear la carpeta .ssh y el archivo authorized_keys por que no existian en el servidor. De todas maneras sigo sin poder clonar el repo. Me aparece el mismo error antes.

Comment: al copiar el contenido de la clave publica generada en la maquina cliente, me aparece el usuario de windows_utilizado@el_nombre_de_pc, eso lo canbié en la copia realizada en el servidor, poniendo el usuario con el que me estoy conectando @ la direccion del servidor. ¿Esto es así?

Comment: Hola Santiago. No deberías crear ese directorio a mano, y si lo haces debes proporcionar permisos 0600 y propiedad del usuario correcto. Si no tiene todo la propiedad y permisos adecuados no te permitirá entrar. Por otro lado que no exista el archivo `authorized_keys` "huele mal" porque debería estar configurado el usuario antiguo, debería estar en algún lado su clave pública autorizada. Ahora estoy viendo que usas el puerto `5918` para acceder al servidor SSH, por lo que es posible que no se trate del servidor `sshd`, si no es otro diferente. ¿Con qué software has montado el servidor de git?